# Why was romaji used when chatting in a video game?

Tags: word-choice

I was watching a japanese stream of a game, and when typing in chat, they were all typing with romaji? Why is that? All there usernames were also all in romanji.
ありがとうございます

Comment: In general, Japanese people do not communicate with each other in romaji. When normal Japanese cannot be used for technical reasons (which is often the case in foreign games), they have no choice but to use romaji instead. Many games only allow the Latin alphabet for account and character names.

Comment: Just to let you know, the spelling is romaji, no n.

Comment: @naruto The did allow for normal Japanese, as they did write in japanese one time, but the rest they wrote in romaji, do you have any other ideas? Thanks for the response

Comment: @Infernoboy Unless you're willing to share the stream, there's no real way for us to know. It's probably easier to ask the streamer or follwers themselves than a third party that doesn't have all the pieces to the puzzle

Comment: In fast-paced games like FPS, players may use romaji for short communication, such as "gomen" ("sorry"), or come up with local romaji argot for quick communication. You must press a key to turn on [IME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method) for Japanese input, and a single keystroke can be annoying in busy games. But if everyone is having long conversations in all romaji, there must be another reason, technical or otherwise.